# SQL 2016 Always on Listener

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2016, listener, windows-server

I have followed many articles on how to get SQL 2016 always on setup and I am hopelessly stuck on the listener.

One of such articles is http://blog.fedenko.info/2016/06/sql-server-2016-always-on-availability.html

Not exactly what I am looking for but very close, I found it very hard to find a clear step by step and many different articles have different ways of doing it.

My listen problem:

On my DC open AD user and computers added SQL-HA-LISTENER as a computer

In DNS added SQL-HA-LISTENER 192.168.10.82

When i ping 192.168.10.82 i get Destination host unreachable

(192.168.10.82 and SQL-HA-LISTENER are not actual computers on the network)

Telnet 192.168.10.82 1433 closed, as to be expected.

I am confused as to what a listener "Is"

Is it a VM with SQL expressed installed on it?

That would be the only thing that makes sense.

If so how do i need to configure it to be a listener?

Comment: I don't think SQL Express supports AGs or BAGs.  That's standard edition or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Listener is a virtual object that "sits" on top of your AG, and directs your traffic.

You can create the Listener object in AD - SQL-HA-LISTENER as a computer, and grant access on it, to the actual computer nodes (replica hosts) that will be in your AG.

Comment: I have been looking for something that like that, When i right click on the SQL-HA-LISTENER computer object and go to properties I do not see a security tab, should I?

Comment: In Active Directory Computers yes, not in DNS.

Comment: Ok got it had to turn on Advanced Features from the View menu in AD.

Comment: FYI - You want to grant full control on the listener computer object to the CNO, not the individual nodes.